# Отправка данных с input в гугл таблицу

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-spreadsheet

Есть ли возможность из input`ов отправлять данные в гугл таблицу?

У меня на сайте имеется форма

```
<form>
<ul>
<li><input.....></li>
<li><input.....></li>
......
<button class="submit" type="submit"/></button>
</ul>
</form>
```

Есть ли возможность по нажатию кнопки передать все заполненные значения с формы в гугл таблицу?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Да , очень просто

в таблице открываете доступ на нее, берете ссылку с ключем, вставляете функцию которая будет прнимать данные в google таблице
и отправляете curl запрос с данными

ознакомьтесь  [с этой статьей](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/46965/)